# Converting 2-D Quantiles to 2-D CDF

Tags: quantiles, cumulative-distribution-function

I've been given some data in a format I've not encountered before - quantiles and associated values in 2-D, e.g. height and weight as:

- For the 10th quantile in the height range, the 50th quantile in the weight range is 60kg
- For the 10th quantile in the height range, the 90th quantile in the weight range is 75kg
- For the 10th quantile in the height range, the 95th quantile in the weight range is 80kg

And a list of quantile values for the height range too (e.g. 10th = 150cm, 20th = 160cm, ...).

I'm wondering how, if at all, I can flip these around into a cumulative distribution function that I can then fit a model to. Is it valid to assume that, for the 50% height and weight quantiles in the example, `CDF(150cm, 60kg)` = `50% * 50%` = `0.25`? Something about that feels a bit iffy.

The actual quantiles provided are pretty sparse (5-10-25-50-75-90-95 in height, 50-90-95 in weight) but in theory there should be enough points to fit to, *if* that assumption is OK?

Comment: Can you share the whole dataset, esp since it seems to have only 28 data points? And if you fit a model to this data, what would you do with the model?

Comment: So unfortunately I can't, because it's medical data (height and blood pressure, I used weight as an example it's more intuitive). The researchers who've asked me to solve this problem want a 2-D gaussian probability distribution function for height and blood pressure.

Comment: Ok. Will you change the question from height to blood pressure? For height and weight I would start with a positively correlated; for height and blood pressure I would start with an uncorrelated model.